# Не работает групповой выбор селекторов в CSS

Tags: css, css3

Есть набор классов, описывающих столбцы разной ширины:

```
.c-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.c-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.c-3 {width: 25%;}
.c-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.c-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.c-6 {width: 50%;}
.c-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.c-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.c-9 {width: 75%;}
.c-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.c-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.c-12 {width: 100%;}
```

Хочется совершать с ними групповые операции по изменению. Но тут возникает сложность. Код такого вида работает:

```
[class*="c-"] {
padding: 0em;
float: left;
display: block;
}
```

Но такой код цепляет вообще всё, где попадается `с-`, например, не имеющий отношения к этому блоку класс `.sec-txt`.

А вот такой код `[class|="c-"]` или такой `[class^="c-"]` - не работает.

Сталкивался ли кто-то с такой проблемой и как её лечить?

Comment: [class^="c-"] - этот вариант должен работать

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/x9ywwejv/

Comment: @soledar10 А если там написано `<div class="item c-6 active"></div>`

Comment: тогда так как Вы уже ниже ответили

Comment: а вот это важно, об этом я совсем не подумал. т.е. то, что они не срабатывают - точно из-за этого. теперь подумаю, как избежать цепляния левых.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Напишите два селектора:

```
[class^="c-"],
[class*=" c-"] {
    padding: 0em;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: то что надо! спасибо!